# Selecting between timezone from timestamp(datetime)

Tags: mysql

How can i select between two times' from datetime column for current day:

Thanks

Comment: Wait, between two *times* or between two *time zones*? MySQL doesn't really have much in the way of *time zone* support.

Comment: sorry , i mean between two times

Comment: Please edit your question then. Also, if this is homework, please add the 'homework' tag.

Comment: i hope you got the edited question....

Answer (score 0):

you would can use `BETWEEN` - for example

```
SELECT <column names> 
FROM <table name>
WHERE time BETWEEN <time1> and <time2>
```

Comment: selecting between minutes in datetime column for current day?

Comment: Use the `TIME()` function - 
WHERE TIME(datetime_col) BETWEEN <time1> AND  <time2>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the basic [select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) down, there is a [convenient operator, `BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html), that will let you pick rows between a pair of values. You can also use the `>=` and `<=` operators. For example, with a table of products and prices, you could find all the products priced between $5 and $10 like this:

```
SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products WHERE product_price BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

alternatively,

```
SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products WHERE product_price >= 5 AND product_price <= 10
```

This assumes your dates are stored in columns of a [date-time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html), and not a text type. If they're in a text type, you should fix that.