# Selecting between intervals of 10 mins from datetime column for current day

Tags: mysql

How can i select rows between intervals of 10 mins from datetime column for current day ?

Any idea?

Comment: I think a little clarification might be necessary? Do you want to group the rows in your table into 10 minute intervals, or something else?

If grouping, you could create a temporary table of minutes, adding 10 minutes to each row, and then joining that to your data and adding a group by statement on the minute column.

If this is the approach you are after, I can write a fuller example if needed.

Comment: Is this homework again, like [Selecting between timezone from timestamp(datetime)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009464/selecting-between-timezone-from-timestampdatetime)?

Comment: I saw your other question with good answers but no upvotes nor accepted answer... it's not good for your reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE dateCol BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: @Rona Finiasi: didn't my post answer your question? Is there something wrong in it?